# Best way to get selected option in drop down list from model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering what the best practice is to select an option from a select field from my database.

I am pulling the data in from my model, but it seems like having an if in every line of code isnt the most efficient.

Here is my current code, is there a better way?

```
<select id="Downloads" name="Downloads">
    <option value="Option1" <% if(Model.Downloads == "Option1"){ %>selected <% } %>>Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2" <% if(Model.Downloads == "Option2"){ %>selected <% } %>>Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3" <% if(Model.Downloads == "Option3"){ %>selected <% } %>>Option3</option>
</select>
```

I have 10 of these select boxes and just want to keep my code clean

Comment: Are you aware that there is an html helper specifically for that? See [Html.DropDown article for more info](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) EDIT: And don't let the jQuery stuff confuse you, the dropdown helper does not depend on jQuery, and really has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ah thanks, Im using the helpers for my other fields but for some reason didn't for the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a SelectList, or a collection of SelectListItems on your model, and then use use DropdownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Downloads, Model.DownloadOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a css class to each select box.Then create an javascript array to save value of them. Following is a way to retrieve value of them and push them into javascript array.

```
  var values =[];
  $(".mySelectBox").each(function(i) { 
    //push to values array
    });
```